# PostgreSQL /dev/urandom

Tags: postgresql, security, cryptography, access-token

Is there a PostgreSQL function that we can use to generate 160 bits of randomness with `/dev/urandom`?

We want to generate an access token.

According to the [OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework: 10.10.  Credentials-Guessing Attacks](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-10.10):

> The probability of an attacker guessing generated tokens (and other credentials not intended for handling by end-users) MUST be less than or equal to 2^(-128) and SHOULD be less than or equal to 2^(-160).

Comment: You may be interested in `gen_random_bytes(int) returns bytea` function of the [`pgcrypto` module](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgcrypto.html).

Comment: Thank you. Does `gen_random_bytes(count integer) returns bytea` use `/dev/urandom`?

Comment: it is available for non-POSIX systems too. For POSIX, I'm not sure, but it's defined to *return `count` cryptographically strong random bytes*, which should be enough for your requirement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like pozs said, you can use `gen_random_bytes(int)` from the [`pgcrypto`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgcrypto.html) contrib module.

This function calls `pg_strong_random` from [`src/port/pg_strong_random.c`](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob;f=src/port/pg_strong_random.c) and throws an error if the return code is `false`.

The comment explains how `pg_strong_random` works:

```
 * Generate requested number of random bytes. The returned bytes are
 * cryptographically secure, suitable for use e.g. in authentication.
 *
 * We rely on system facilities for actually generating the numbers.
 * We support a number of sources:
 *
 * 1. OpenSSL's RAND_bytes()
 * 2. Windows' CryptGenRandom() function
 * 3. /dev/urandom
 *
 * The configure script will choose which one to use, and set
 * a USE_*_RANDOM flag accordingly.
 *
 * Returns true on success, and false if none of the sources
 * were available. NB: It is important to check the return value!
```

You can look into `include/pg_config.h` in your PostgreSQL installation and see which source for random numbers is used.

If you are on Linux, you'll probably use OpenSSL as source for randomness.

The [manual page for `RAND_bytes`](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Manual:RAND_bytes%283%29) claims:

> RAND_bytes() puts **num** cryptographically strong pseudo-random bytes into **buf**.

I did not dig into OpenSSL source since that really hurts, but essentially, if you trust OpenSSL, you can also trust `pgcrypto`.

Comment: I cannot find anything containing `RANDOM` in my `include/pg_config.h`. What happens if it is missing?

Comment: Just checked that it seems like the flags names are different on my system, I just found `HAVE_RAND_OPENSSL`, but no luck with the Windows or `/dev/urandom` flags.

Comment: It shouldn't be missing. Did you run `configure`? Are `USE_DEV_URANDOM`, `USE_OPENSSL_RANDOM` and `USE_WIN32_RANDOM` in your `pg_config.h.in` file?

Comment: I'm not compiling postgresql at the moment. I'm trying to find out if the Postgres in our production environment has those flags enabled. It is already installed (via apt on Debian), the version is 9.4. `configure` has been run for sure during the installation via apt.

Comment: And I cannot find those flags neither in `pg_config.h`, nor with `pg_config --configure`. But finding `HAVE_RAND_OPENSSL` might mean that they have different naming on our system, and that `DEV_URANDOM` isn't enabled, only `OPENSSL_RANDOM` is. The problem here is that `HAVE_RAND_OPENSSL` is undefined and I cannot find any other of those flags defined.

Comment: Reading `configure.in`, the case is like this: if `configure` was run with `--with-openssl`, then you'll have `USE_OPENSSL_RANDOM`, if not, you'll have `USE_DEV_URANDOM`. This logic can be overridden by specifying `USE_DEV_URANDOM=1` on the command line explicitly (which you'd probably see in `pg_config --configure`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I wasn't able to find that clarification. We're using OpenSSL.